# how to remove an element in html string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

I have a Html String and I want to parse it to html and then remove any `pre` tags and it's children.
I tried this:

```
HTMLString = "<p>a paragraph</p><p>second Paragraph</p><pre>&lt;script&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;function (){&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;something();&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&lt;/script&gt;</pre>";
var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML(HTMLString));
alert($jQueryObject.find('pre').length);
```

but this alert me 0 that means it can't find any `pre` tag.
can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

[this is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mosijava/s93u7d17/2/)

```js
HTMLString = "<p>a paragraph</p><p>second Paragraph</p><pre>&lt;script&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;function (){&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;something();&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&lt;/script&gt;</pre>";
    var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML(HTMLString));
alert($jQueryObject.find('pre').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because `<pre>` is in root level of the string. For that case `filter()` works but it would not find another `<pre>` if it was nested inside another of your elements

Typically you want to insert the string into another container and use `find()` on that other container so you don't need to worry about nesting levels.

```js
HTMLString = "<p>a paragraph</p><p>second Paragraph</p><pre>&lt;script&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;function (){&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;something();&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&lt;/script&gt;</pre>";

//changing your code to use `filter()` 
var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML(HTMLString));
console.log('Filter length:', $jQueryObject.filter('pre').length)

// Using `find()` within another container
var $container = $('<div>').append(HTMLString);
console.log('Find length:', $container.find('pre').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
HTMLString = "<p>a paragraph</p><p>second Paragraph</p><pre>&lt;script&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;function (){&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;something();&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&lt;/script&gt;</pre>";
    var $jQueryObject = $("<div/>").html(HTMLString);
    console.log("Befor Remove tag: "+ $jQueryObject.find('pre').length);
    $jQueryObject.find('pre').remove();
    console.log("After Remove tag: "+ $jQueryObject.find('pre').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a DOM tree using your HTML string by appending to a DOM element, then you can use `find()` to get the `pre` tag element.

```js
var HTMLString = "<p>a paragraph</p><p>second Paragraph</p><pre>&lt;script&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;function (){&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;something();&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&lt;/script&gt;</pre>";
var $jQueryObject = $('<div>').append($(HTMLString));
console.log($jQueryObject.find('pre').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```